# Svg texpath disappears in firefox when you change pointer events

Tags: svg, firefox

```js
document.getElementById('frame-5416779E-782A-462E-AEC1-2FBCA08DAF42').onmouseover = function(){
        this.style.pointerEvents = 'all';
    };
```

```html
<div id="frame-5416779E-782A-462E-AEC1-2FBCA08DAF42">
  <svg style="width: 437.953px; height: 45.7323px; overflow:visible;" viewBox="0 0 437.9527559055118 45.73228346456693">
    <text width="100%" height="100%">
        <textPath width="100%" height="100%" href="#00d08f3b-2fa0-485e-acb6-f59b8384bbd4">
            <tspan xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/textLayout/2008" color="#b49d5b" fontsize="11">TEST</tspan> 
        </textPath>
    </text>
    <path id="00d08f3b-2fa0-485e-acb6-f59b8384bbd4" d="M0 10 L 100 10" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="0px" fill="transparent"></path>
  </svg>
</div>
```

This works in all browsers, if you hover "TEST" pointer events are added and nothing happens.
If you do the same in firefox, the text disappears.

Now the weird part ... if you go to element inspector and toggle the overflow css of the svg .. it magicly reappears.

Is this a bug in firefox? any workarounds?
I must be able to turn on/off the pointer events for editable svg elements (this is just a small part of the whole)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in Firefox. It's been fixed now, the fix will appear in Firefox 87.

In the meantime here's a workaround. Rather than setting the path to transparent, make it a child of a `<defs>` element.

I've removed some other pointless attributes too.

```js
document.getElementById('frame-5416779E-782A-462E-AEC1-2FBCA08DAF42').onmouseover = function(){
        this.style.pointerEvents = 'all';
    };
```

```html
<div id="frame-5416779E-782A-462E-AEC1-2FBCA08DAF42">
  <svg style="width: 437.953px; height: 45.7323px; overflow:visible;" viewBox="0 0 437.9527559055118 45.73228346456693">
    <text>
        <textPath href="#00d08f3b-2fa0-485e-acb6-f59b8384bbd4">
            <tspan xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/textLayout/2008" color="#b49d5b" fontsize="11">TEST</tspan> 
        </textPath>
    </text>
    <defs>
        <path id="00d08f3b-2fa0-485e-acb6-f59b8384bbd4" d="M0 10 L 100 10"/>
    </defs>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx! you saved my life ;) i'll report this on bugzilla!

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1691659